# How to handle backspace in NSComboBox with swift 5

Tags: macos, swift5, nscombobox

I have NSComboBox with external datadource and I'm using method:

```
(NSString *)comboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox completedString:(NSString *)string
```

to complete string with suggestions, everything is working all right except when I press backspace, it won't autocomplete. I have tried to debug and it didn't even call this method on backspace. I have also tried call it directly from method:

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
```

but it wont select completed string that way. 
My question is what am I doing wrong? Is there better way to handle delete or I should just try to select completed text programmatically?

Comment: What is your expected behaviour when the user presses delete?

Comment: Good example is in Photoshop when you are choosing fonts: it should delete letter from control text, but make suggestion which should be selected, so when you type you can retype throught selected (sugested area))

Comment: Are you sure you mean delete and not backspace?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry yes backspace I will edit it in question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `controlTextDidChange` to detect when backspace was pressed, then trigger completion manually using `complete` on `NSTextView`:

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (... /* backspace pressed */) {
        NSTextField *textField = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];
        [textField complete:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: how to tell, if backspace was pressed? I can store my own most recent value, but can't distinguish from pasting a value.